# How to create instagram API subscription using cURL

Tags: api, curl, instagram

Following the instagram API documentation, I ran the following in the command line:

```
$ curl -F 'client_id=my_client_id' \
> -F 'client_secret=my_client_secret' \
> -F 'object-geography' \
> -F 'aspect=media' \
> -F 'lat=35.657872' \
> -F 'lng=139.70232' \
> -F 'radius=1000' \
> -F 'callback_url=http://http://requestb.in/my_string' \
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

and got the following error:

```
Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I did try curl --help and curl --manual, but wasn't able to figure this out based on their contents.  How might I successfully create a subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing problem with this one:

```
> -F 'object-geography' \
```

It supposed to be `Key=Value` paired parameter. But you are using only one. So check this out. Probably it will be

```
> -F 'object=geography' \
            ^ check this
```